# select only vertex from TRAVERSE outE(), inV() FROM ... command

Tags: orientdb

I have a SQL Command that currently works just fine as below

```
select from (traverse outE(), inV() from (select from Foo where name='root') while active=true) where @class='Foo'
```

However I think it will not work for the case I have many different types of vertex connected together. Therefore I need to replace the where condition with something like

```
select from (traverse outE(), inV() from (select from Foo where name='root') while active=true) where @elementType='Vertex'
```

Is there special function to determine element type which is available in Java API (OrientElement.getElementType())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this as where condition:

```
where @this instanceof 'V'
```